# Probabilty of sharing birth months

Tags: probability

I'm stuck on formulating the expression to solve the following two-part question:

**Problem Statement**

Given 4 people,
(a) the probability that **at least** two share a birth month
(b) the probability that **exactly** two share a birth month

Therefore my entire event space would contain 12*12*12*12 (20736) events.

**My attempt**

Part (a), of which I'm fairly confident is correct

```
p(at least two) = 1.0 - p(all distinct birthdays)
                = 1.0 - (12 * 11 * 10 * 9)/(12^4) 
                = 1.0 - 11880/20736
                = 0.427
```

Part (b) I'm stuck on what seems to be the first step, which would be formulating the probability as a difference of 1.0 and another probability, as I did in part a. My first thought was:

```
p(exactly two) = p(at least two) - p(all three have same birth month)
```

If that expression is correct, I could use the value from part (a), but then I'm unsure on how to solve for `p(all three have same birth month)`.

**Questions**

1. Is my assumed formula for part (a) correct?
2. Is my assumed formula for part (b) correct? If so, how can I solve for `p(all three have same birth month)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part a looks good.

In part b, you seem to have forgotten that there are *four* people. While your approach might work, the true formula would be more complicated, taking into account the exactly three case, the all four case and the two pairs case.

In the end I believe it easier to decide which two are going to share (this can be done in $6$ ways), look at that duo as a single unit, and calculate the odds of the duo and each of the two remaining people having three different birth months. All in all the probability of exactly two of the four sharing a birth month is
$$
\frac{6\cdot 12\cdot 11\cdot 10}{12^4}
$$

Comment: Oh okay I see my mistake, you are correct. So I would essentially be doing `p = p(at least two) - p(at least 3 share) - p(all 4 share)`?

Comment: No, you would be doing $$p(\text{at least two share}) \\-p(\text{exactly three share})\\ -p(\text{all four share}) \\-p(\text{two pairs share one month each})$$

Comment: Gotcha. That way ends up being more complicated than I originally thought, I'll go with the method you suggested :)